# Being able to tap on ONLY one item in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, listview

So I have a subclassed `UITableView` that lists data. I need to make only one cell selectable.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// rows in section 0 should not be selectable
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (indexPath.row == 3) {
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    NSLog(@"Hey whats up, address");
    return indexPath;
}
else {
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
   return nil;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

My code that does this so far works, but only after the cell is clicked at least once. Placing it in didSelectCell allows the cell to be selected if held down for 1-2 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do that in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

// your code
if(indexPath.row != 3)
{
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
{

}
```

And then on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   if(indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        //do your stuff
    {

}
```